# Consulta SQL com array PHP

Tags: php, sql, array, select

Tenho uma array que será variavel, ex: $ref = array('123', '654', '555').

eu queria fazer uma consulta SQL para trazer as informações dessas referencias, algo como:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela_itens
WHERE ref = (array do PHP)
```

Como posso fazer isso?

A consulta simples que faço, sem array, está assim:

```
$query = ("
SELECT *
FROM tabela_itens
WHERE ref = '123'
");
$db -> setQuery($query);
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $row){
    echo '<div>'.$row->ref.'</div>';
};
```

Comment: pode usar `.....WHERE ref IN (value1, value2, ...);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// exemplo array do PHP
$ref = array('123', '654', '555');

$in = '(' . implode(',', $ref) .')';

$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tabela_itens WHERE ref IN ' . $in;
```

- Implode cria uma string a partir de um array dividindo os valores do array com uma vírgula (ou qualquer valor que você preferir).
- O operador `IN` permite que você especifique vários valores em uma cláusula WHERE.

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/qftt3k)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o array da seguinte forma (Considerei que os dados precisam ser passados dentro de aspas simples. Caso não seja necessário, basta utilizar o implode como indicado nas outras respostas):

```
<?php

$parametros = array_map(function($element){
    return sprintf("'%s'", $element);
}, array(1,2,3));

$query = sprintf("
    SELECT *
    FROM tabela_itens
    WHERE ref in (%s)
", implode(',', $parametros));
```

conteúdo final de $query:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM tabela_itens
    WHERE ref in ('1','2','3')
```

**Lembrando que não se deve confiar nos dados inseridos pelo usuário. O que significa que a utilização da biblioteca PDO é extremamente recomendado, utilizando de fato funções que limpem quaisquer lixo dos dados.**